# Clear Hibernate validator messages

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have a page (a popup) with some fileds. When I submit the form on this page, the validation is triggered and the errors appear.

The problem is that, if I close the popup and reopen it, the error messages are still on that page. How can I clear the validations when the popup is reopened?

The page is made with JSF.

Thanks!

Comment: In future JSF questions, please always mention exact JSF impl/version and any component library make/version. Otherwise you can hardly get a single suitable answer which you can directly apply on your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Let ajax update the popup before you open it.

It's unclear what component libary you're using for the popup, but assuming that it's PrimeFaces, it should look like this:

```html
<h:form>
    ....
    <p:commandButton ... update=":dialog:form" oncomplete="dialog.open()" />
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dialog" visible="false" ...>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:messages />
        ...
        <p:commandButton ... oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dialog.hide()" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```