# p:dialog does not fire ajax close event when using dialog.hide()

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, dialog, primefaces

I'm using `<p:dialog>`. After submitting the form therein, I use `dialog.hide()` and it fires the ajax close event listener method which will update a `List<E>`.
It was working properly, but when I put some required input components and bring the `<p:dialog>` again if there is some validation error, it doens't fire the method anymore.

The dialog:

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:dialog id="dialogComentario" header="Deixe sua avaliação" widgetVar="confirmation" 
        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" height="340" width="500" modal="true" 
        visible="#{not empty facesContext.maximumSeverity}" 
        resizable="false" closable="true" draggable="false">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            ...
            <p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-primary btenviacoment" 
                oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) confirmation.hide();" 
                actionListener="#{comentario.actEnviarComentario}" global="false">
                <i class=" icon-play-circle icon-white"></i>
                <h:outputText value=" Enviar Comentário" />
                <f:param name="codigoplu" value="#{produto.produto.codigoplu}" />
            </p:commandLink>
            ...
            <p:commandLink styleClass="btn" onclick="confirmation.hide();" 
                global="false" immediate="true">
                <h:outputText value=" Cancelar" />
                <i class="icon-off"></i>
            </p:commandLink>
            ...
        </h:form>
        <p:ajax event="close" update=":avaliacoesClientes, :dialogComment" 
            listener="#{produto.atualizarComentarios}" global="false" />
    </p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

The action listener method:

```
public void actEnviarComentario(ActionEvent event) {
    String codigoplu = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("codigoplu");
    PegarDadosCliente();

    try {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.util.Date utildata = new java.util.Date();
        utildata = (java.util.Date) f.parse(String.valueOf(data.getValue()));
        java.sql.Date datasql = new java.sql.Date(utildata.getTime());

        Comentario comentario = new Comentario(Integer.parseInt(usuario.getId()), Integer.parseInt(codigoplu), titulo.getValue().toString(), mensagem.getValue().toString(), datasql, Integer.parseInt(rating.getValue().toString()), new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime()));
        listavelComentarios.inserirComentario(comentario);

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("confirmation.hide();");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to close the dialog with `RequestContext` as shown in action method, but that won't fire the ajax close event either.

Here's the ajax close event listener method:

```
public void atualizarComentarios(CloseEvent event) {

    try {
        comentarios = comentario.listarComentarios(codigoplu);

        if (comentarios.size() > 0) {
            msgAvaliacao = "Avaliação do produto.";
            int votos = 0;

            for (Comentario comentario : comentarios) {
                votos += comentario.getAvaliacao();
            }

            rating = votos / comentarios.size();
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post `p:dialog` tag?

Comment: sorry, i missed. Updated.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it in *Ajax* way? I make this question because I see you're complicating your code in some way. I think it's easier just to use `h:commandLink` with `action` methods and `ajax="false"`. That will make a submit, you can refresh what you want there and once back the dialog will not be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is not related to validation. Remove all those input components and press the command button/link and you'll see that it's still not fired.

This problem is caused by the unnecessary combination of `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">` and `visible="#{not empty facesContext.maximumSeverity}"`. The output panel keeps auto-updating the dialog which apparently forces you to set the `visible` attribute like that. The dialog is auto-updated right before the `oncomplete` event is fired. If the dialog `visible` property is `false`, then the dialog is already hidden (invisible) before the `oncomplete` is fired.

So, just get rid of the `<p:outputPanel>` and the `visible` attribute. Your `oncomplete` already does the right job.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `RequestContext` line is unnecessary. You're already hiding it in `oncomplete` which is perfectly fine. See also [Keep p:dialog open when a validation error occurs after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-up-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @BalusC. But when I use the other button "Cancel" which just use 'onclick="confirmation.hide();" the close event is called.

Comment: You're right. It's quite possible that this is just a bug in PrimeFaces it doesn't invoke the close event when it's currently handling a postback. I edited the answer accordingly. You might want to report it to the PF guys.

Comment: I made another test @Balusc, and changed the "cancel" button to "oncomplete" too, and it works (still calling close event)! Also, I use to have this method called  (close event), but I had problems to keep <p:dialog> up when a validation error occurs... After I made <p:dialog keep up, the method stops fire...

Comment: I now see it. The `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">` + `visible` is causing this. As I already mentioned in my initial answer, that whole thing is completely unnecessary. But now it turns out that it actually caused the whole problem. So just removing them should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the changes that you said, and everything works but clear the inputs components, any idea? when I try to open the <p:dialog> the inputs components still have the values...

Comment: Ajax-update the dialog's content before opening it. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614047/clear-hibernate-validator-messages/10618108#10618108